# simple form, getting empty strings in result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Hey I trying to populate a many to many association through a collection of checkboxes in my form. However, the result is always prepended with an empty string

```
= simple_form_for([:companies, @view_model.sales_price]) do |f|
  = f.input :name, autofocus: true
  = f.input :margin_percentage
  = f.association :carrier_products, as: :check_boxes, include_hidden: false
```

result

```
[..., ..., ""]
```

I pass in the `include_hidden` tag, but it doesnt help

any advice?